# I do not understand result obtains for Q1 and Q3 with np.boxplot

Tags: python, numpy

If I define

```
>>> y=np.linspace(1., 10, 10)
```

and I do

```
>>> np.percentile(y, [25, 50, 75])
```

I obtain [3.25, 5.5, 7.75].
For the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 series, Q3= 5.5 (OK) and Q1=3 (and not 3.25) and Q3=8 (and not 7.75) !!!
Sorry I am a little lost with these elementary things ..thanks by advance for some help.

Comment: Please better explain what confuses you or what you expect, so that people can help.

Comment: My problem is if I take a book of mathematic and I follow the rules for a serie 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 I find Q1=3 Q2=5.5 and Q3=8 !!!

Comment: For example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quartile.html with Tukey method which seems to be a standard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I like to understand exactly how things are working ... And because someone else might be like me ...

Firstly I thank a lot BrenBarn for his  help and the time he spent for
answering. So how plt gives the results for first quartile (Q1, 25th percentile), the median (Q2, 50th percentile) and 3th quartile (Q3, 75th percentile) in plt.boxplot() and more generally with np.percentile() ?

BrenBarn said to read the manual http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html where it is writen "linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.", but for me it was not very clear because i, j and fraction were not obvious for me.
So let's do :

```
>>> x=np.linspace(1,10,10)
>>> x
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
>>> np.percentile(x,[0,1,20,25,50,75,80,99,100])
[1.0, 1.0900000000000001, 2.8000000000000003, 3.25, 5.5, 7.75, 8.1999999999999993, 9.9100000000000001, 10.0]
```

The way to deduce i,j and fraction is, if we take the definition of numpy manual:

P: percentile to calculate.

N: total number of data.

n=((P/100)*(N-1))+1.

n=k+d.

k is an integer, the ith sorted data of the array x (let's say v_i) and d is the fraction described in the numpy manual for percentile(). v_i+1 is called vj (the (i+1)th sorted datum).
So using the definition of the numpy manual:
n=i+fraction.

Then the result is found easily by using:

value= first sorted data (x[0] in this exemple) **if P=0**.

value= last data (x[9] in this exemple) **if P=100**.

value= v_i + d * (v_j - v_i) **if 0 < i < N**.

*For exemple above:*

- For the First percentile:

n=((1/100)*(10-1))+1=1.09

and

```
>>> x[0]+0.09*(x[1]-x[0])
1.0900000000000001
```

OK, as returned by np.percentile(x,[0,1,20,25,50,75,80,99,100]) above.

- For the 20th:

n=((20÷100)*(10-1))+1=2.8

and

```
>>> x[1]+0.8*(x[2]-x[1])
2.7999999999999998
```

OK, very near of the return of np.percentile(x,[0,1,20,25,50,75,80,99,100]) above.

- For the first quartile:

n=((25/100)*(10-1))+1=3.25

and

```
>>> x[2]+0.25*(x[3]-x[2])
3.25
```

OK, as returned by np.percentile(x,[0,1,20,25,50,75,80,99,100]) above.

- For the median:

n=((50/100)*(10-1))+1=5.5

and

```
>>> x[4]+0.5*(x[5]-x[4])
5.5
```

OK, as returned by np.percentile(x,[0,1,20,25,50,75,80,99,100]) above.

- And so on ...

I used this link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Microsoft_Excel_method to do it, where this method is called the "Microsoft Excel method". Because I am from the free world I do not like it but this is the name given in this link ...

Hoping this will help someone, despite my bad English writing.

Je suis Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

By default, numpy uses linear interpolation for percentiles, meaning that if the "true" value of a percentile lies between two data points, it returns a value that is between them, proportionally closer to the data point that is closer to the requested percentile.

Starting in numpy 1.9.0, you can override this by passing the `interpolation` parameter to `percentile`.  You have several options as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).  "Lower" or "nearest" is likely what you're looking for.

In earlier versions of numpy there is no way to get the behavior you want.  There is a function [`scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile.html) in scipy which provides "lower" and "higher" interpolation methods (but not the extra "nearest" and "midpoint" methods that `np.percentile` offers).

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in the case of this series we should obtains Q1=3 and Q3=8 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quartile.html by using Tukey method. In this case no need of interpolation ...

Comment: It is the same result  with plt.boxplot and before using the box plot in my project I want to be sure that all is as I am expecting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @servoz: numpy is not using the Tukey method.  It is using the linear interpolation method described on the documentation page I linked to.

Comment: Again me ! I totally understand now, and according to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_Linear_Interpolation_Between_Closest_Ranks_method it seems that it is not the  linear interpolation method that is used but the Microsoft Excel method described in this link (with the linear interpolation we find well Q1=3 Q2=5.5 Q3=8 but with " Microsoft" method it is  Q1=3.25 Q2=5.5 Q3=7.75). May be it was for this reason that I did not understand because I had never thought that python use a Microsoft method .... the worm is in the fruit ?

Comment: @servoz: Look man, I don't know how else to explain it.  Go to this page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html .  See where it says "linear: `i + (j - i) * fraction`, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j."?  *That* is how the percentile is computed.  It's not "a Microsoft method".  It's a linear interpolation computed exactly as described there.  That's all.

Comment: @ BrenBarn. My friend I have read and read again this link. But the  sentence "where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j" is not very very

Comment: @ BrenBarn. My friend I have read and read again this link. But the  sentence "where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j" is not very clear for me. However if I use n=P/100*(N-1)+1, as described in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_Linear_Interpolation_Between_Closest_Ranks_method in the Microsoft excel part I obtains the same result than python. Anyway I know how it is working and it is the more important. Thanks for your help .